# I couldn't store the values in database from the custom form in HTML page. Using Django

Tags: python, django

This is my views.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'Login/index.html', args)
```

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models


class Customer(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    password1 = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.company + ' - ' + self.fname
```

Following is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Customer


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = (
            'fname',
            'company',
            'email',
           )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user= super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.UserName= self.cleaned_data.get['name']
        user.CName = self.cleaned_data.get['cname']
        user.Email = self.cleaned_data.get['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

And HTML file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
<title>Customer Desk</title>
   {% load static %}
<link  href="{% static 'css/Styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
/>
</head>
<body class="login">
<!-- header starts here -->
<div id="desk-Bar">
    <div id="desk-Frame">
      <div id="logo"> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/Home/">Virtual Agent 
      </a></div>
    <div id="header-main-right">
      <div id="header-main-right-nav">
        <form method="post" action="" id="login_form" name="login_form">
          <table border="0" style="border:none">
            <tr>
              <td ><input type="text" tabindex="1"  id="mail" 
placeholder="Email or Phone" name="email" class="inputtext radius1" 
value="">     </td>
              <td ><input type="password" tabindex="2" id="pass" 
placeholder="Password" name="pass" class="inputtext radius1" ></td>
              <td ><input type="submit" class="fbbutton" name="login" 
value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>
              <input id="persist_box" type="checkbox" name="persistent" value="1" checked="1"/>
              <span style="color:#ccc;">Keep me logged in</span></label>
</td>
          <td><label><a href="" style="color:#ccc; text-decoration:none">forgot your password?</a></label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- header ends here -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6">
            <div class="loginbox radius">
             <h2 style="color:#336; text-align:center;">Welcome to Virtual 
Agent</h2>
             <div class="loginboxinner radius">
                <div class="loginheader">
                 <h4 class="title"></h4>
                 </div>
                 <!--loginheader-->

ejiofhndouiwefhnouiewnhfounhefoufnheohu3jogsdhfbviurehjnmihmeju hguihg 
9uhe39u8gt 43y3489yt398thy983gt3hy4988498gty4h
                <!--loginform-->
            </div>
            <!--loginboxinner-->
        </div>
<!--loginbox-->
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="loginbox radius">
            <h2 style="color:#336; text-align:center;">Welcome to Virtual 
Agent</h2>
            <div class="loginboxinner radius">
                <div class="loginheader">
                <h4 class="title">Connect with friends and the world around 
you.</h4>
                </div>
            <!--loginheader-->
                <div class="loginform">
                    <form id="login" action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <p>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" 
placeholder="Your Name" value="" class="radius mini" />
                        <input type="text" id="company" name="cname"  
placeholder="Company Name" value="" class="radius mini" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" 
placeholder="Your Email" value="" class="radius" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="pass" 
placeholder="New Password" class="radius" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        <input type="password" id="rpassword" name="rpass" 
placeholder="Re-Enter Password" class="radius" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                        <button class="radius title" name="signup">Sign Up 
for Virtual Agent</button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <!--loginform-->
            </div>
            <!--loginboxinner-->
        </div>
        <!--loginbox-->

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

please anybody help me. Because i have tried my best to register a person and save data in models.Customer. But i cant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use User of Django admin  , and create a customer model how is related to User by one-to-one relationship , and use signals on creation , this may help you : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/23/how-to-add-user-profile-to-django-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

The fields in your HTML file don't match up at all with the fields in your form class. Therefore, the form is not valid; but you are not displaying the validation errors that would show you what was wrong.

However, even if you made this work, you **must not do this**. You are creating your own User model that saves passwords in plain text. Do not do this. Django has a very good authentication framework which allows you to customise your models as much as you like; you should use it.

Comment: What should i do? I mean how i do this. I am going to develope a website this is the first step where users can register them...

Comment: As I said, use Django's authentication framework. There is [very detailed documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/) on Django's docs site. Also, learn how to use [forms in your template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-template).